# External Development and Testing of Microsoft Access VBA Code

Tags: ms-access

Are there tools (IDEs, editors, and so on) available to develop and test Microsoft Access VBA code outside of Access' built-in VBA environment, or is that essentially creating a full Visual Basic Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of something like that.

You can create code and controls in other languages and embed/run/use them in Access (OCX, Com-Interop...), but if you really mean writing and running **Access VBA** outside of Access...I'm quite sure that's impossible.